# Zeppelin spark innterpreters throws java.lang.StackOverflowError after running a while

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin to run some spark job with crontab.
jdk8,spark1.6.2,scala2.10
But In the last days,I found Zeppelin's spark interpreter shut down almost every day once or more.
And here is the log

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4183)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4197)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.asSeenFrom(Types.scala:754)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.computeMemberType(Types.scala:788)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol.typeAsMemberOf(Symbols.scala:2655)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberType(Types.scala:779)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(Types.scala:1534)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingleType.underlying(Types.scala:1486)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingletonType.widen(Types.scala:1340)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.toPrefix$1(Types.scala:4541)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4556)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4183)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4197)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.asSeenFrom(Types.scala:754)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.computeMemberType(Types.scala:788)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol.typeAsMemberOf(Symbols.scala:2655)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberType(Types.scala:779)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(Types.scala:1534)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingleType.underlying(Types.scala:1486)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingletonType.widen(Types.scala:1340)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.toPrefix$1(Types.scala:4541)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4556)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4183)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4197)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4638)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.asSeenFrom(Types.scala:754)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.computeMemberType(Types.scala:788)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol.typeAsMemberOf(Symbols.scala:2655)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberType(Types.scala:779)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(Types.scala:1534)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineUnderlyingOfSingleType(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingleType.underlying(Types.scala:1486)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingletonType.widen(Types.scala:1340)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.toPrefix$1(Types.scala:4541)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:4556)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:4183)
```

........

It was a very very long log, seems to be a loop
I have adjust the env like this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/hadoop/jdk
export MASTER=spark://namenode:7077 
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=10001
export SPARK_HOME=/home/hadoop/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 5g --driver-class-path /home/hadoop/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/extlib/oracle-driver.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/extlib/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client-spark.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/extlib/spark-csv_2.10-1.3.0.jar:/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/lib/*:/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/*::/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/conf:/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/interpreter/spark/*::/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/conf:/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/conf:/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/lib/zeppelin-interpreter-0.6.0.jar/home/hadoop/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark-0.6.0.jar" 
export ZEPPELIN_MEM=-Xmx4096m
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason.

First,zeppelin use scala 2.10.4 and spark 1.6.2 use 2.10.6
remove the scala lib in zepplin_home/lib and put the scala libariry 2.10.6

secondly,restart the spark interpreter sometime,other wise all the task will be excuted on the only spark application.As the time flow,the application will shutdown by memory issues.just add a cron noteboot and check the "auto-restart interpreter on cron execution" on

this job will shut down the older spark interpreter and start a new one.